# C++ MinGW how to compile for Linx from Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw

I currently have MinGW for Windows and would like to develop for Linux(I have read that I need Headers), where would I get Linux headers and set up to compile both Windows and Linux programs with MinGW code::blocks.

Note: I have researched but could not find anything from Windows to Linux only Linux to Windows.

Comment: Can't you just install Linux in a VM and develop using GCC instead of going through the trouble of figuring this stuff out?

Comment: Yes, I do have CentOS in VM, but I was thinking it would be easier this way.

Comment: No, it really wouldn't be. Cross-compilation from Windows to Linux is ugly. Use the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not exactly see what you mean by "develop", but if you want to work in an environment that produces binaries for some Linux system, you can not really "develop" because you cannot really run / debug them on Windows (when using cross-compilation).

On the other hand, if you want to develop code that compiles on Linux, you are already there. Since you are developing using MinGW, you are pretty much guaranteed that your code will compile under Linux with corresponding version of GCC. To produce a binary for the Linux distribution of choice, you can use VM, speed should not matter since you are not probably going to do it often.